# How to disable hotjar on localhost rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotjar

when I access localhost, those sessions are included in hotjar statistics.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Something like checking the current environment (`Rails.env.production?`)?

Comment: @SebastianPalma good idea, I was thinking of disabling on the hotjar configs, I didn't think to do it in the app itself. I'll look into your suggestion now and report back what I find.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to only use hotjar in production (thanks to @SebastianPalma for this solution):

```
<% if !current_page?(controller: 'home', action: 'dashboard') %>
  <% if Rails.env.production? %>
    <script>
        (function(h,o,t,j,a,r){
            h.hj=h.hj||function(){(h.hj.q=h.hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
            h._hjSettings={hjid:2019490,hjsv:6};
            a=o.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            r=o.createElement('script');r.async=1;
            r.src=t+h._hjSettings.hjid+j+h._hjSettings.hjsv;
            a.appendChild(r);
        })(window,document,'https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-','.js?sv=');
    </script>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you want to exclude hotjar from certain pages even in production (e.g. your admin dashboard), wrap the above code in this:

```
<% if !current_page?(controller: 'home', action: 'dashboard') %>

<% end %>
```